# List the most up-to-date product of each category,postqresql queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

```
user_id product_id  category_id date_added  date_update
1              2        1           2.3.2021    null
1              3        1           2.3.2020    2.4.2023
1              4        2           2.3.2020    null
1              5        2           2.3.2020    2.4.2023
2              5        2           2.3.2020    2.4.2023
2              4        1           2.3.2020    null
```

List the most up-to-date product of each category

Comment: (1) Show the results you want.  (2) How do you treat NULLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(parition by userid,category_id order by date_update) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

OR you can also use `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (user_id,category_id) *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY user_id,category_id, date_update
```

Comment: but your answer returned one user ,ı want all user this like

Comment: @user14184824,I've updated the answer - you can check now

Comment: I checked but just return one user from different categories

Comment: @user14184824, create your table here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11

Comment: @user14184824, check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7c76cf4af43fa9a03f62bd0f41bc5df8

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=65dce8adc315d30d9c30b728b8671a80

Comment: @user14184824, check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b5b412d1d62fc9ac4014f09ddbffe050

Comment: we can get user_id another table and we say if user_id this table ...  must do ,how can  doing?

Comment: and your answer get date_added or date_update just one

Answer (score 0):

> List the most up-to-date product of each category

You can use `distinct on`.  Let me assume that if the update date is null, then you want the creation date:

```
select distinct on (category_id) t.*
from t
order by category_id, coalesce(date_update, date_added) desc;
```

If you wanted this per user/category combination, the logic would be:

```
select distinct on (user_id, category_id) t.*
from t
order by user_id, category_id, coalesce(date_update, date_added) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Window function

```
select u_id,c_id, p_id, coalesce (date_update, date_added) as date ,
rank () over (partition by u_id, c_id order by coalesce (date_update, date_added) desc) as r
from inventory
) t where r = 1
```